# Поменять местами слова между разделителем

Tags: delphi

Сделала вот такой код.

```
var
  List, New_list:TStringList;
  i:Integer;
begin
  List :=TStringList.Create;
  New_list :=TStringList.Create;
  List.NameValueSeparator :='-';
  List.LoadFromFile('test.txt');
  for i := 0 to List.Count-1 do New_list.Add(List.ValueFromIndex[i]+'-'+List.Names[i]);
  New_list.SaveToFile('result.txt');
  FreeAndNil(List);
  FreeAndNil(New_list);
end;
```

Пытаюсь переделать код на чтение построчно (**Тут остановилась и не знаю как дальше исправить**):

```
var
  List, New_list:TextFile;
  s:string;
  index: integer;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then begin
  AssignFile(List, OpenDialog1.FileName);
  Reset(List);
  AssignFile(New_list, ExtactFileDir(OpenDialog1.FileName)+'\out.txt');
  Rewrite(New_list); // чтобы создался новый, если нету, или перезаписался с нуля
  Append(New_list); // чтобы можно было добавлять строки, а не перезаписывать каждый раз
  begin
while not eof(List) do
  begin
    Readln(Lists, s);
    index := Pos('-', s);
    if index > 0 then
    begin
      s := Copy(s, index + 1 - index) + '-' + Copy(s, 1, index - 1);
    end;
    Writeln(New_Lists, s);
  end;
FreeAndNil(List);
FreeAndNil(New_list);
end;
  end;

end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Снова здравствуйте, Татьяна.

Здесь совсем не нужны `TStringList`-ы. Для каждой строки из исходного файла определяйте положение тире (`-`) - функция `Pos`. Если тире там есть, компонуйте новую строку для записи в файл из двух кусков (функция `Copy`) с тире между ними.

```
var
  ...
  index: integer;
begin
  ... 
  while not eof(List) do 
  begin
    Readln(List, s);
    index := Pos('-', s);
    if index > 0 then
    begin
      s := Copy(s, index + 1, Length(s) - index) + '-' + Copy(s, 1, index - 1);
    end; 
    Writeln(New_List, s);
  end;
...
```

Comment: Тут совсем запуталась. И пока что не могу решить эту задачу. Если есть возможность то помогите подправить как должно правильно быть. :(. Хотя я стараюсь.

Comment: Igor, Исправила код, посмотрите вверху. Работает, но почему то в конце ошибка: Access Violation. Что это может быть ? Заранее благодарна.

Comment: @Татьяна Замените оба `FreeAndNil` в конце на `CloseFile` :).

Comment: Аяяй , вот я бландинка. Спасибо работает. Это я упустила :))). От чистого сердца спасибо.